# store file skipped character

Tags: java, file-io

In a file I am skipping number of characters from beginning of file

```
InputStreamReader isr = new FileInputStream(fis);
isr.skip(skipNumberOfCharacter);
```

I am able to store the remaining character in BufferString like this:

```
while ((ch = isr.read()) != -1) {
                sb.append((char) ch);
            }
```

But I want to store the characters skipped from InputStreamReader. Suppose these are the content of my file:

**12345678910**

I skipped first 5 characters, So I want to hold **12345** in my StringBuilder object.

Comment: Do you want to know how to read the first n characters from a reader into a buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you read in two buffers like:

```
int byteCount = 0;
int skipMark = 5;
while ((ch = isr.read()) != -1) {
   if(byteCount < skipMark)
      skipBuffer.append(ch);
   else
      sb.append((char) ch);
   byteCount++;
}
```